# LOCK_EX para Race Condition é uma potencial solução?

Tags: php, sistema-de-arquivos, io

Recentemente, em uma [discussão no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485718/if-two-people-are-appending-to-a-file-with-file-put-contents-are-the-strings-mer), um usuário recomendou que, ao usar a flag `LOCK_EX` em um `file_put_contents` já iria bastar, pois a função iria automaticamente aguardar ([comentário](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485718/if-two-people-are-appending-to-a-file-with-file-put-contents-are-the-strings-mer#comment41605953_26485782)) até que o arquivo seja liberado para ser escrito.

```
file_put_contents("log.txt", $log_text, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Em um cenário que um thread `n` está escrevendo no arquivo e outros `N` threads estão esperando pela liberação, qual destes `N` threads irá ser o próximo a escrever no arquivo? Existe alguma fila para isso sendo que todos estão aguardando simultaneamente?

Na documentação do *php.net*, [este comentário](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php#120880) menciona:

> You do not need LOCK_EX if you write only to a file (like log files). Multiple writing processes are already queued. Test it on your own by calling this script 4 times simultaneously:
>
> *[...]*

Por suma minha dúvida é: se vários threads estiverem tentando escrever em um arquivo `log.txt` que está travado, o `file_put_contents` irá liberar o lock para qual thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim e não. Quero dizer, tudo vai depender do que de fato precisa, se for executar múltiplos processos paralelos, visando entregas mais rápidas, ainda pode ter problemas. Também depende do que os scripts paralelos irão fazer com o mesmo arquivo, se irão gravar de outra forma, então o `LOCK_EX` não vai ter resolvido ou sido necessário, o que não seria um problema de condição corrido, mas sim de lógica mesmo.

É importante ter em mente que alguns sistemas operacionais, o `flock()` é implementado no nível do processo. Ao usar uma API de servidor *multithread* (ISAPI, exemplo: FastCGI, FPM, etc), você pode não ser capaz de contar com `flock()` para proteger arquivos contra outros scripts PHP rodando em threads paralelas da **mesma instância do servidor**, então aqui poderá ter problemas (dependendo de como vai usar).

> **Nota:** Apesar de improvável, apenas para mencionar, `flock()` não é suportado por sistemas de arquivo antigos, como FAT. É improvável se aplicar a qualquer cenário atual, mas isso é só para termos como nota.

Se fizer algo como (descartando os cenários que citei acima) vai notar que o `file_put_contents` vai ficar travado:

**foo.php**

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("log.txt", 'w');
flock($handle, LOCK_EX);

sleep(1000);
```

**bar.php**

```
<?php
file_put_contents("log.txt", 'foobars', FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Então até que o primeiro `fopen()` seja fechado com `fclose()` ou outro script encerre (aonde o [Garbage Collection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) (GC) vai cuidar de liberar o `LOCK`), você ficará com o segundo script (do exemplo: bar.php) travado, resolveria a condição corrida, mas ainda sim **não** teria entregas mais rápidas, o que talvez dispensaria a necessidade de processos paralelos, ou melhor, precisará analisar toda as *regras de negócio* para planejar tudo o que deverá ocorrer. Se a ideia não for tempo de entrega, mas apenas evitar conflitos na gravação, então usar `LOCK_EX` resolverá (existe alguns detalhes importantes que explico no final).

Agora falando de outros cenários, imagine que você terá processos paralelos que irão abrir arquivos existentes, mas variados, e precisa que ao abrir por um processo o outro ignore o arquivo (acaso tente abrir o mesmo). De forma simples ambos ainda poderão abrir, mesmo com `LOCK_EX`, só não irá ocorrer no mesmo momento, pois o segundo processo irá esperar até que o primeiro libere o arquivo, se a necessidade fosse que se um processo já resolveu o primeiro arquivo, o segundo devesse ignorar o já resolvido, usar apenas `LOCK_EX` não vai resolver, vai ter que checar com `flock` se o arquivo já está com LOCK, para isso é preciso usar a flag `LOCK_NB`, que não travará o script, mas fará o `flock()` retornar um booleano que informa, sendo `false` significa que outro "processo" já está com `LOCK_EX`.

> **Nota:** Em versões antigas do Windows ou do PHP com Windows (não me recordo ao certo, irei editar com detalhes) talvez não tenha suporta para `LOCK_NB`

Algo como:

```
<?php

$a = fopen("log.txt", 'a');

if (flock($a, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    sleep(1000); // simulando um script demorado
} else {
   // Realiza ação alternativa
}
```

Dessa forma se outro processo estiver com LOCK você poderá pular para o próximo ou simplesmente encerrar o script desnecessário (tudo depende das suas necessidades especificas)

Existe mais uma ressalva sobre o `flock()`, para que funcione todos "processos" devem usar a mesma forma de bloqueio, ou então isso não irá funcionar.

Respondendo sobre o tal comentário:

> You do not need LOCK_EX if you write only to a file (like log files).
> Multiple writing processes are already queued ....

É o tipo de situação que a pessoa fala *"funcionou para mim"*, e lendo o código fonte do *php-src* (e até aonde consegui compreender): [ext/standard/file.c#L619](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/4ccf0b01819677dbdd3fbb330f9220606866028b/ext/standard/file.c#L619), existem duas condições no `PHP_FUNCTION(file_put_contents)`:

```
if (flags & PHP_FILE_APPEND) {
    mode[0] = 'a';
} else if (flags & LOCK_EX) {
    ...
    mode[0] = 'c';
}
```

Essas condições aparentemente são apenas para definir o modo de abertura do arquivo:

| Modo | Código | O que faz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `a` | `mode[0] = 'a';` | Abrirá apenas para escrita e colocará o ponteiro do arquivo no final do arquivo. Se o arquivo não existir, tentará criá-lo. |
| `c` | `mode[0] = 'c';` | Abrirá o arquivo apenas para gravação, se o arquivo não existir, ele será criado, se existir, não será truncado (em oposição a `w`) e não falhará (como é o caso de `x`). O ponteiro do arquivo está posicionado no início do arquivo. |

Isso não quer dizer que o código do `file_put_contents` terminou ali, se voltar até a linha 617 (do script atual, no futuro o script pode ser mudado), vai notar que o contexto é definido exatamente como o usuário desejar (segundo parâmetro):

```
context = php_stream_context_from_zval(zcontext, flags & PHP_FILE_NO_DEFAULT_CONTEXT);
```

Para que depois seja executado, aberto o arquivo (quinto parâmetro irá passar o `context`):

```
stream = php_stream_open_wrapper_ex(filename, mode, ((flags & PHP_FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH) ? USE_PATH : 0) | REPORT_ERRORS, NULL, context);
```

Então, ao menos internamente no script, o `LOCK_EX` faz sim diferença no `file_put_contents`, o `PHP_FILE_APPEND`:

```c
#define PHP_FILE_APPEND (1 << 3)
```

**Não** definir por conta e internamente a *flag* `PHP_LOCK_EX`:

```c
#define PHP_LOCK_EX 2
```

Você é quem deve dizer que deseja o *travamento exclusivo*.

---

Reforçando, tudo depende do que você precisa é estar bem definido sobre a necessidade e de como vai projetar, caso contrário (se não for adequadamente planejado):

- Pode ainda sim ter problemas diferentes após liberar o LOCK (dependendo do que os scripts paralelos irão fazer)
- Todos que acessarem o(s) mesmo(s) arquivos devem ser feitos da mesma forma, caso contrário poderá ainda ter problemas
- Dependendo do sistema que use multi-thread (como ISAPI) pode ser que você não possa contar com o `flock()`